# Understanding \ and \\ in Windows address bar, or How \ is internally interpreted in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, operating-system, environment-variables, reverse-engineering

How does \ in Windows address bar resolves to %SYSTEMDRIVE%\ after hitting enter, while / opens internet explorer with http:/// in the address bar while /{something} resolves to opening internet explorer with http:///{something} or www.{something}.com in the address bar?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: When you type \ (backslash) in the address bar of Windows Explorer on a Windows operating system (Windows 7 in my case) and hit the enter key, the Windows Explorer opens the system drive for you (typically C:\\). But when you enter / (frontslash) in the Windows Explorer followed by the enter key, it takes you to the internet.

Comment: Well, that's nice to know, but it's not a question. What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: How does Windows resolve \ to C:\ in Windows Explorer? Is \ an environmental variable, an internal constant or something else?

Comment: How is \ internally interpreted in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The `http://` thing is just some weird logic of Windows Explorer; most probably, if it sees only forward slashes assumes that it's an URL (as forward slashes are generally used for URLs on Windows), but it's just some corner case of Windows Explorer heuristic, which is neither contractual nor particularly interesting.

What actually matters from a programming standpoint is how the Win32 APIs treat paths; this is explained in details in [this often-referred-to MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).

> How is `\` internally interpreted in Windows?

Each process has a global *current directory*, set at startup and changeable via the `SetCurrentDirectory` API; `\` is resolved to the root of the drive of the current directory (and paths starting with `\` refer implicitly to that drive).

So, if the current directory of Windows Explorer is `c:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop`, `\` will resolve to `c:\`.

Notice that in Win32 APIs *when dealing with Win32 paths* (*not* UNC paths) the forward slash (`/`) is interpreted in the same way as the backslash (`\`), so in a "regular" Win32 program doing `SetCurrentDirectory` to `/` will be the same as with `\`; as stated above, it's just a choice of the parser of Windows Explorer to try to use it as a part of an URL.